# How to iterate through a nested dict in puppet?

Tags: ruby, puppet

Here is the python example of  a data set i have in my puppet code  similar to the below, :

```
dict = {'account1': {'uid': ['123456'], 'user': ['appuser1'], 'appname': ['myapp1']},
       'account2': {'uid':['567878'], 'user':['appuser'2], 'appname':['myapp2']}}
for i in dict.keys():
     print dict[i]['user'], dict[i]['uid']
```

How do i achieve the same solution in puppet/ruby.TIA.

Comment: `dict.each {|_,data| print(*data.values_at(:user,:uid))}` should do it

Comment: @engineersmnky It works in Ruby; Puppet has its own iteration DSL. https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6.18/lang_iteration.html

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs TBH I have never used puppet. This showed up in my prefiltered [tag:ruby] search and I thought simple enough from a ruby perspective.

Answer (score 3):

In Puppet manifests, you can iterate over a hash using the [`each` function](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/lang_iteration.html):

```
$ cat foo.pp
$dict = {
  'account1' => {
    'uid'     => ['123456'],
    'user'    => ['appuser1'],
    'appname' => ['myapp1']
  },
  'account2' => {
    'uid'     => ['567878'],
    'user'    => ['appuser2'],
    'appname' => ['myapp2']
  }
}

$dict.each | $account_key, $account | {
  notice("${account['user'][0]}, ${account['uid'][0]}")
}
$ puppet apply foo.pp
Notice: Scope(Class[main]): appuser1, 123456
Notice: Scope(Class[main]): appuser2, 567878
Notice: Compiled catalog for it070137 in environment production in 0.04 seconds
Notice: Applied catalog in 0.03 seconds
```

If you like, you can use types to check that the key and value in the hash are what you expect:

```
$dict.each | String $account_key, Hash $account | {
  notice("${account['user'][0]}, ${account['uid'][0]}")
}
```

Comment: I used this way.

```$dict.each |String $key, Hash $value| {
if 'user' in $value {
   notify { ${value[user][0]}```